This looks like another inappropriate VTC to me
See this question on our main boards:  Does the universe not being locally real mean anything for our daily lives?
The OP asks a legitimate question, that philosophy has sought to address -- "how should we live", and relates that to recent physics discoveries that bear on fundamental oologic and epistemic assumptions behind philosophic worldviews. The answer's that "extrapolating physics discoveries to global worldviews may be unjustified" is entirely on topic here, will lead to a limited number of good answers, and is a very useful bit of wisdom for our visitors to take away from philosophy.  Note that there were already several good answers making this point posted, at the time this question was (I believe) inappropriately closed.
The OP's distrust of what science has shown -- that QM is non-local and unreal, is itself unjustified, but can be mostly ignored in good answers. An OP question need not be 100% good before it can have a good answer.
That emergence is the mechanism to limit global anti-locality and anti-realism may be uncomfortable for some advocates of global reduction here.  I hope that limiting the realization that to have a realist worldview, we all have to embrace emergence was not the motivation behind these VTCs.

Lowri did point out what clarification was necessary, didn't they?

What the hell. Not my cup of tea, but I'll see if I can't tighten the jib.

@controlgroup all of Lowri’s requests were minor reference issues.

"you say this is more to do with QP not being locally real — more compared to what? what is the other aspect of the question" - that seems like a decent clarification to me, among the others.

"another" seems utterly unnecessary in the question title


Does the universe not being locally real mean anything for our daily lives?

My only complaint is that the question is too broad for a simple Yes/No answer. I can't really do anything about the QM non-local nature of the Universe.
So if I'm into stoicism then the answer is no but other philosophical schools may reach a different conclusion.
The question does not lead to a single definitive answer but it does provide multiple interesting (and likely conflicting) answers.

Questions in philosophy pretty much never have only yes or no answers. There is always narrative and caveat needed for even the simplest answer.
